# Why margin issue in IE and Chrome but not in firefox?

Tags: css, margin

I don't understand why there is a margin issue between the top menu and the slider in IE and Chrome. It looks fine in firefox?

(link was removed due to canceled project)

// Dan

Comment: I am viewing your link. i don't find any margin issue. May i know what the exact problem is ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a div

```
<div class="sf-right">&nbsp;</div>
```

between the menu and slider which is causing that to happen. Remove the div or add the following style to the css

```
.sf-right {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking in the code of the page I found a little spacer under the menu.

```
<div class="sf-right">&nbsp</div>
```

It seems that in Firefox the next div is rendered over this little boy, in other browser it became a space. I dont know what's his function, but you can take 2 action:

1. remove it
2. use the css to put it on the left of the menu bar.

I saw another little glitch in the footer. You used percentage to specify right margin of the components of the footer. This is good in most cases, but it can cause glitch in case of different sizes of scrollbar. 
To fix it change the percentage from 5% to 4%